# SQL select statement with WHERE clause based on name

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table `TBL_TEST` which has a column `NAME` with 5 rows, and those rows have the values 'Balkhab', 'Gosfandi', 'Sancharak', 'Aqcha'

I want to write a query with a `WHERE` clause that when the value in where class match with one of the values in NAME column in `TBL_TEST` then it should show only that value but when it does not match then it should show all the values in the table, below is select statement that is not working as   expect.

```
SELECT NAME 
FROM TBL_TEST 
WHERE NAME = 'Balkhab'  OR NAME != 'Balkhab'
```

[image: picture]

Comment: what you mean by `value in where class match with one of the values in NAME column in TBL_TEST`?? From where value will come in where clause??

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: `X OR NOT(X)` always evaluates to true, so you will be selecting all records with the WHERE clause you have.

Comment: Thank you very much everyone you could solve my problem

Comment: This is Oracle, and a strange question to ask. I would wonder what problem you are trying to solve...

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you want something like this:

```
SELECT NAME
FROM TBL_TEST
WHERE NAME = 'Balkhab'
UNION ALL
SELECT NAME
FROM TBL_TEST
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TBL_TEST WHERE NAME = 'Balkhab');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  IF Exists(select 'X' FROM TBL_TEST WHERE NAME = 'Balkhab') 
        SELECT NAME from TBL_TEST WHERE NAME = 'Balkhab' 
    ELSE 
         SELECT NAME FROM TBL_TEST
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one below

```
select * 
from table where not exists (select name from table where name = 'Aqcha') or   
name ='Aqcha'
```

Comment: if my answer helped you please mark it as correct answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can write a stored procedure for it with one parameter.

```
Create procedure(@Name varchar(max))
As 
begin
    If(Isnull(@name, 0))
    Begin
        If exists (select 1 from TBL_TEST xx where xx.name = @name)
        Begin
            Select * 
            From TBL_TEST 
            Where name = @name
        End
        Else
        Begin
            Select * 
            From TBL_TEST
        End
    End
    Else
    Begin
        Select * from TBL_TEST
    End
End
```

Pass your name as parameter to the stored procedure to get require result
stored procedure are the best option as you can avoid network traffic, less bandwidth as you can pass only require parameter and get required result

Comment: The OP is on Oracle